# save items in a listbox

Tags: c#, listbox, save

In my C# windows application (using visual C# 2012 if you need to know) I need to add things to listboxes and save the items so when the program closes they stay there next time it opens. I would prefer not using the settings to store the information.

Some more things I need for this. Saving them to a text file can't happen either. It needs to be saved in a way that it can not be edited outside of the program.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry but its not possible.  Anything that you `save` can be modified by another program.

You could sign the saved data and then detect that some other has modified the data, but you cannot prevent other programs from read/changing the data.

**EDIT**

DPAPI can be used to encrypt/decrypt the data.  See [Really simple encryption with C# and SymmetricAlgorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9031537/really-simple-encryption-with-c-sharp-and-symmetricalgorithm)

Comment: I mean it cant be edited easily like opening a text file and changing 25 to 10000000 just like that.

Comment: Then encrypt the data before saving it.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that

Comment: Use DPAPI (its easy).  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9031537/really-simple-encryption-with-c-sharp-and-symmetricalgorithm

Answer (score 0):

Set up SQL on a web server.

Save the info to your web server.

They can't modify data on a remote server, so I think a database is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

If you are the only person using that program... I mean... if you are the only one that knows what the program is doing, you could go for saving data in binary format into binary files. I doubt that someone looking at your files will say "Oh damn there is a .bin file in this directory! I have to find a way to discover how to read it and what's it's content!".

As long as you keep your program and its sources protected... I doubt someone will get something out of that content. You transform all your data into a Byte[], you compress it, you encrypt it and you write in a file. Bye bye.