# Adding "Promo Code" functionality to my ASP.NET C# website

Tags: c#, asp.net, encryption, hash, promotion-code

The idea is I'll have a page that will accept a user's promotion code.  When the user clicks "Submit", the code will make a call to the database to ensure that the promo code is indeed valid.  I plan on having a "PromoCode" table in my database which contains a list of available promo codes and a bit variable called something like "HasBeenClaimed".  I'm not all that familiar with encryption/etc. but I would imagine that I would want to **NOT** store the actual clear text promotion code in this table but rather something like an encrypted/hashed/etc. version of it.  So, if someone maliciously gains access to the table's data, they couldn't do anything with this hashed version of the promo code.

Anyways, so functionally, the user submits their promo code and the code does something like takes its hashed value and compares it with what's in the database.  If it matches a record in the database and "HasBeenClaimed" is `false`, they continue on with the promo.

I am speaking purely pseudocode, and my terminology might not be correct.  But I think you get the basic idea of what I want.

My promotions are not of high value - they're "Get the first two months half off" (which equates to $25 off each month for two months).  Just FYI, I created a PayPal button that reflects this promotion to be used on the web page that the code will direct to if the promotion code is indeed valid.

**QUESTION** I don't know exactly where to start with this nor do I know common best practices when it comes to "Promo Codes".  Please advise on common best practices regarding implementing promo code functionality in an existing ASP.NET website -any advice would be great.

Comment: unless the codes are really long, hashing won't gain you anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to this question depends a lot on what kind of promos you are going offer.

If the promo is fairly low value, like `Get 1 dollar discount on you next purchase of 5 dollars or more` then I don't see much point in protecting the promo code(s) in the database. In a scenario like that, losing the promo code(s) to a hacker is not going to be the worst disaster. Rather, the mere fact that the hacker gained access to the database will be much more worrying than a few stolen promo codes.

If, on the other hand, the promo is high value, like `Be one of the three out of 2 million users that wins a new car` then it would make much sense to protect the promo code. In such a scenario you must make sure that:

1. The promo code itself is sufficiently long and random (making it random enough can be quite tricky) so that it becomes practically impossible to guess it.
2. The promo code is stored in a fashion that protects it if someone gains access to it's storage location. Storing it in some sort of hashed or encrypted (but with encryption you have a new problem, keeping the encryption keys safe) form would likely be the best bet. You could even break it up somehow and store part of it in several different places.

Keep in mind that in this case, your coworkers (and you) are the prime hacker candidates. Even if they are not eligible to claim it, they could steal the code and give it to their second cousin on their mother's side (or similar).

Also, the admins at you site host need to be kept from figuring out what the codes are from their storage form.

Also also, make sure that the page where the user enters his promo code is using SSL to prevent someone from intercepting it in transfer.

---

More generally speaking, you need to decide if promo codes are going to be single use or if several people can use the same code.

It's not uncommon to have promos like `Visit us on [popular social network] to get a free baseball cap with your next purchase`. In this case it makes sense to allow each user to use the same promo code even if there is a risk that someone might get his/her hands on the code without actually visiting.

You could of course support both types (single/multiple use).

You also need to figure out how the promo codes are generated and distributed. Do you send them out in email campaigns? Do you print them in a local news paper? Are you going to print paper coupons and hand them out or snail mail them to people? Must the user break 20 captchas to gain a code?

And you need to decide who is eligible to use a promo code. Must it be a registered user or can anyone use it? How does an unregistered user use it?

---

Technically the options are many. It depends on what kind of web application we are talking about. I would first try to figure out what kind of different promotions to support. Candidates:

1. Additional discount on purchase
2. Free additional promotion product
3. Free shipping on the next order
4. 2 months access to otherwise inaccessible part of the site
5. (etc)

Then I would build the framework (database tables, business logic etc) around the types of promotions I want to support. Personally I would not make separate pages for each promotion. I would try to integrate the promo into the existing flow of the site as much as possible.

Comment: Thanks for the in depth answer.  Bounty awarded :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple hashing method you run in your codebehind:

```
string ClearTextPromoCode = TextBox1.Text;
byte[] ClearTextByteArray = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(ClearTextPromoCode);

System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1 SHA1Encryptor = new System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();
byte[] EncryptedByteArray = SHA1Encryptor.ComputeHash(ClearTextByteArray);
string EncryptedPromoCode = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(EncryptedByteArray);
```

SHA1 is quick, one-way, unbreakable, and perfect for this use. You do not add plain-text codes to your database - instead, you run them through this encryption method, and then add them to the database. When a user enters a promo code, you run their text through the same encryption method, and then perform the database query with the encrypted string.

The purpose of this is that the hashed values in your database, if stolen, will do the thief no good - he cannot simply enter these strings on your website - they would be run through the encryption again and not match anything in your database.

It seems like you want the promo-codes to be single-use only. Most checkout systems let you validate your promo-code before the final purchase. I would advise you allow users to make sure their promo code is valid, and only mark the `HasBeenClaimed` database column after the sale has gone through.

*Warning:* You should be aware that SHA1, while mathematically unbreakable, can be circumvented using "rainbow tables". A hacker creates a program which runs every word in the dictionary (and then some) through a SHA1 hasher, and the then does a reverse-lookup on the hash he stole from you. The way to prevent this is using a "salt" - adding  a public, random string to the beginning (or end) of each promo code before it is hashed, completely changing the end result. You store the salt in plain-text in the database. But do you really need to worry about someone stealing your 20% off coupons? ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple encryption for this, when saving the promo code in database encrypt it.

Then when user enters the promocode, encrypt with the same key and compare in database, if it matches the key in database, accept that promocode and mark the bit field as true meaning it has been used.

Some simple encryption c# codes:

> [Simple insecure two-way "obfuscation" for C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/165808/simple-2-way-encryption-for-c-sharp)
>
> [Really simple encryption with C# and SymmetricAlgorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9031537/really-simple-encryption-with-c-sharp-and-symmetricalgorithm)